# ubuntu is not booting up as it should

Tags: boot, login, nvme

I installed the disruptive Ubuntu after a couple of failed attempts when the nvme key was not responding to my credentials but now after pacifying a couple of nuisance I can login with out major issues, but this evening I tried to login and the screen just turned black and would not boot up to nvme key login nor user interface login.  Im coming back from a bad sking accident so my memory is foggy following the flame like a moth, How to fix this so that I can have a flawless and secure boot up?

Once again thank you for your assistance,

Sincerely

Mr bazzaru